# I have an issue using the multiprocessing module under python 2.7 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing

I was using a huge scientific code on Linux using the multiprocessing module to accelerate some computations. Somewhere in a library that I am using the multiprocessing is called this way :

```
        manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
        return_dict = manager.dict()
        n=0
        while n <n_samples:
            if n + n_procs < n_samples:
                n_subs = n_procs
            else:
                n_subs = n_samples-n
            jobs = []
            for i in range(n_subs):
                index = n+i
                x_in = samples[index]
                p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.__worker, args=(index, x_in, return_dict))
                jobs.append(p)
                p.start()
```

I wrapped the top level call of this code in my main python script as following :

```
if __name__ == '__main__' :
    freeze_support()
    fitting.optimize()
```

As the :

```
fitting.optimize()
```

line calls the parallel code

Still while launching the code I have an error occuring and I do not know why :

```
File "C:\Users\XXX\workspace\git-DLLM\Simulation\CFD_Data_Analysis\Fitting3DPanels\CoeffFitting3DPanels.py", line 48, in <module>
fitting.optimize()
 ....
  File "C:\Users\XXX\workspace\git-MDOTools\modules\MDOTools\ValidGrad\FDGradient.py", line 97, in grad_f
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()

 File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 99, in Manager
m.start()

 File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 528, in start
self._address = reader.recv()
EOFError
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, Windows, and Multiprocessing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041404/python-windows-and-multiprocessing)

Comment: Actually even if the error occurs at the very same point I do not think it is the same issue. In the given link the guy has an import error which does not happen in my code ...